# Swift: String Concatenation for Outlet names

Tags: swift, string-concatenation

I'm looking to reduce the number of lines in my code, I have quite a lot of label names that correspond to their values. I was wondering if there is a way of setting these values in a for-in loop or something similar. Right now I'm struggling to find a way of concatenating the label names to make them dynamic. I'm not sure if I'm able to do this in Swift, any thoughts? Thanks.

This code

```
LabelGiraffe1.text = "This is Giraffe 1"
LabelGiraffe2.text = "This is Giraffe 2"
LabelGiraffe3.text = "This is Giraffe 3"
LabelGiraffe4.text = "This is Giraffe 4"
LabelGiraffe5.text = "This is Giraffe 5"
```

To something cleaner like...

```
for number in 1...5 {
  LabelGiraffe + /(number).text = "This is Giraffe /(number)"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an array of labels and over them:

```
let giraffeLabels = [LabelGiraffe1, LabelGiraffe2, LabelGiraffe3, LabelGiraffe4, LabelGiraffe5] 

for (index, label) in enumerate(giraffeLabels) {
  label.text = "This is Giraffe \(index + 1)"
}
```

You can also make `giraffeLabels` as stored or calculated property of your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `IBOutletCollection`. It's effectively like putting all your outlets into an array (which is what it does in the background, I believe). You can then iterate over them, or access them by index, as you're trying to do.

More information here: http://nshipster.com/ibaction-iboutlet-iboutletcollection/

Comment: The problem with IBOutletCollection is that it doesn't keep the items sorted. You need to sort them first somehow (e.g. by their tag). Or you can build the array of labels dynamically `let labels = [LabelGiraffe1, LabelGiraffe2, LabelGiraffe3, LabelGiraffe4, LabelGiraffe5]`